# C++ plot data library

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, plot

I am looking for a simple data plotting library for c++. I use MSVS 2012, Win 7, Qt5. I want to create 2D plots to visualize some data sets.
I read about some plotting libs but I am still looking for more information. Here is what I found so far:

koolplot: Seem to be too basic and doesn't look up to date
qcustomplot: Looks very good, but I didn't find instructions for installation on MSVS.
cern root: Very heavy and I think documentation for Win + MSVS is poor.
gnuplut: I read about gnu c api, but I want to create a standalone app, which doesn't depend on other apps to be installed.
qwt: too heavy and bad documentation for MSVS

Can somebody recommend a good c++ lib for plotting 2D data, if possible with integration in a qt project?